# Localhost/Phpmyadmin: when exporting a database a very unusual file in kb getting downloaded and it has only errors

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to export a database on my localhost/phpmyadmin and a very strange Sql file in kb getting downloaded like this:

[image]

When I opened this file it has only errors like this (a lot of errors, a glimpse of it is given below):

[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple debugging, I found the solution:

The issue is `max_input_vars` variable of `php.ini` file was commented on and has a very low value.

I have uncommented it and increased the value from 1000 to 10000.

After that, I have restarted Xampp and it works now.

Here is the graphical representation:

a) open `php.ini` file.

[image]

b) search for `max_input_vars` variable:

[image]

c) If its commented, then uncomment it and increase its value from 1000 to any higher value

[image]

d) save it and now ***restart Xampp server (or Apache and MySQL)***

**Note:** restart of Xampp (or Apache and MySQL) is a must-step to do.

Thanks